# Searching for a quote from a Drizzt do' Urden book

Tags: quotes, legend-of-drizzt

I don't have access to my books and have no PDF version of them, nor being able to find it using Google (seems I'm good at find anything with Google except from book quotes)

I'm searching for a quote from one of the books of the first trilogy, probably the second or the third. It's a dialogue between Montolio and Drizzt, where Montolio Debrouchee explain to Drizzt that we get suffering to learn and happiness to stand the suffering. Can anyone find it and paste it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in the third book, *Sojourn*, not long before Mooshie's death.

> "But you are still a child," Montolio said. "Five years is not five hundred, and five hundred is what you have remaining. Promise me now that you will reconsider
>   your course when I am no more. There is a wide world out there, my friend, full of
>   pain, but filled with joy as well. The former keeps you on the path of growth, and
>   the latter makes the Journey tolerable.
>   "Promise me now," Montolio said, "that when Mooshie is no more, Drizzt will go
>   and find his place."